# Pointing to an empty struct

Tags: c, pointers, struct, segmentation-fault, initialization

I'm curious why the following segfault occurs:

```
typedef struct Book {
    char* title;
    unsigned int year;
} Book;
```

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[]) 
{
    Book *hammy;
    printf("Hammy is located at %p.", hammy);
    printf("Hammy has the title: %s.", hammy->title);
}
```

> Hammy is located at 0x55a3629e0340. 
> Segmentation fault (core dumped)

For example, why doesn't `hammy->title` print an empty string or `\0` or some gibberish or whatever? When the pointer to the (undefined) `Book` is created, what does it point to start?

Comment: Uninitialised variables have no value. An uninitialised pointer doesn't point at anything.

Comment: @rici -- I see, so what is the address `0x55a3629e0340` from? Is that some place in the bss section or something?

Comment: It's just random unspecified bits. (If you really want an answer: it's whatever bits happened to be where the compiler chose to place that variable.) There's no reason to believe that it's a valid address.

Comment: Try printing `hammy->title` as `%p`. I bet it's NULL. `%s` has to access the memory at 0, which you likely don't have access to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hammy` is declared as type `Book *`, a pointer to Book, just an integer. But it is [*uninitialized*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uninitialized_variable). It will contain whatever garbage was on the [stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack-based_memory_allocation) at that moment. In my case it's 0.

You can print `hammy` because it's just an integer. When you try to dereference the pointer with `hammy->title` the operating system won't let you. Either the memory it points to does not belong to the process, or it's null. You get a [segmentation fault](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault).

You need to initialize it with something.

```
Book *hammy = &(Book){
    .title="Nothing in This Book Is True, but It's Exactly How Things Are",
    .year=1994
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly,

Book *hammy;

This means that you are declaring the pointer variable. As it is not initialized with any address of the book variable, it will be containing the random address. That's why segmentation fault.

Secondly,

Variable of the book is not declared so how we can get content of it, declaring a pointer does not mean that we are declaring an instance of the book. We are just telling the pointer that the address stored in **hammy** will be pointing to an instance of Book type.